# Trying to mock/replace functions inside functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

here's the code i'm trying to mock:

```
stats.totalRequests.labels('incoming').inc(x);
```

i tried:

```
const incFunc = function inc(a) {
        return true;
    };

const stats = {
   totalRequests: {
       labels: (a, b, c) => incFunc(a)
            }
    };

module.__set__('stats', stats);
```

i also tried setting labels as sinon.stub() instead.
but i keep getting the error TypeError: stats.totalRequests.labels(...).inc is not a function.

any ideas how i can achieve this? i don't need any functionality, i simply don't want the original line in the code to do anything. it can be a stub/empty function or whatever
Thanks much

Comment: You need to modify `labels` to return an object with a property of `inc`, which is a function.

Comment: but isn't labels also a function?

Comment: It is but you need to make it *return* an object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to make `labels` return an object with a property of `inc`.

Example:

```js
const stats = {
  totalRequests: {
    labels(arg) {
      console.log('labels: ' + arg);
      return {
        inc(x) {
          console.log('inc: ' + x);
        }
      };
    }
  }
};

let x = 12;
stats.totalRequests.labels('incoming').inc(x);
```